# Shell Script : how to make getopts just read the first character post `-`

Tags: bash, shell, parameters, getopt

I have a shell script `testShell.sh` which uses `getopts` as below:

```
#!/bin/bash
while getopts ":j:e:" option; do
    case "$option" in
        j) MYHOSTNAME=$OPTARG ;;
        e) SCRIPT_PATH=$OPTARG ;;
        *) ;;
    esac
done

echo "j=$MYHOSTNAME"
echo "e=$SCRIPT_PATH"
shift $((OPTIND - 1))
echo "remaining=$@"
```

When I test run it like following:

```
$ testShell.sh  -jvalue1 -evalue4 -Djvalue3  -pvalue2
```

The output which I get is following:

```
j=value3
e=2
remaining=
```

But I would like the output as:

```
j=value1
e=value4
remaining=-Djvalue3 -pvalue2
```

**Is it possible to make sure that** `getopts` **only looks at first character post** `-` **symbol?** so that it doesn't interpret `-Djvalue3` as `-jvalue3` and `-pvalue2` as `-e2`.

Comment: Please don't multipost: also asked on [superuser](http://superuser.com/q/456191/4714) and
[unix&linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/44450/4667)

Comment: I will make sure that I don't do this again. But I was in need of this badly and did so in desperation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After posting it on 3 forums and searching everywhere... eventually I tried the following and it worked...

```
testShell.sh  -jvalue1 -evalue4 -- -Djvalue3  -pvalue2
```

Notice

```
--
```

after `-evalue4`

And the output was

```
j=value1
e=value4
remaining=-Djvalue3 -pvalue2
```

I believe `--` asks `getopts` to **stop processing options.**

EDIT:
[Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean) is the link which explains how this work.

Comment: Very nice. You can add this link to your answer: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean

Answer (score 1):

You can add a break after `j)`:

```
#!/bin/bash
while getopts ":j:e:" option; do
    case "$option" in
        j) MYHOSTNAME=$OPTARG ; break ;;
        e) SCRIPT_PATH=$OPTARG ;;
        *) ;;
    esac
done

echo "j=$MYHOSTNAME"
echo "e=$SCRIPT_PATH"
shift $((OPTIND - 1))
echo "remaining=$@"
```

Output:

```
$ bash test.sh -jvalue1 -Djvalue3 -pvalue2
j=value1
e=
remaining=-Djvalue3 -pvalue2
```

Output with spaces between option / arguments:

```
$ bash test.sh  -jvalue1 -evalue4 -D jvalue3  -p value2
j=value1
e=value4
remaining=jvalue3 -p value2
```

Comment: I could but then it will not read the e parameter... `testShell.sh  -jvalue1 -evalue4  -Djvalue3 -pvalue2` will also return `j=value1
e=
remaining=-evalue4 -Djvalue3 -pvalue2` but I would like `j=value1
e=value4
remaining=-Djvalue3 -pvalue2` 
I have updated the example to be more clear.

Comment: Why isn't there spaces between the option and the argument? I updated my post.

Comment: `-pvalue2` and `-p value2` are not the same at all. When they are linked e is an option, when they are separated `e` is within the argument of option `p`.

Comment: +1 Thank you @Ayoubi. I was able to find a solution for this. :)

Comment: This could still work: after `esac` you could add `[[ -n $MYHOSTNAME ]] && [[ -n $SCRIPT_PATH ]] && break` to get out of the while loop. Still `-j` and `-e` have to appear before any other options.

Answer (score 1):

You could do your option processing manually:

```
set -- -jvalue1 -evalue4 -Djvalue3 -pvalue2

remaining=()
for arg; do
    case $arg in
        -j*) j=${arg#-j} ;;
        -e*) e=${arg#-e} ;;
        *)   remaining+=($arg) ;;
    esac
done
printf "%s='%s'\n" j "$j" e "$e" remaining "${remaining[*]}"
```

which outputs

```
j='value1'
e='value4'
remaining='-Djvalue3 -pvalue2'
```

This way you don't have to rely on the user inputting the arguments in a particular way,  such as adding `--` in the middle, or forcing `-j` and `-e` to come first.